# vb.net json serialize outlook mailitem userproperties returns partial blank

Tags: json, vb.net, outlook

I'm trying to stringify serialize Outlook MailItem UserProperties (IEnumerable) but keep getting back blank values like so:

[{},{},...{}]

The MailItem is a custom form!.

The number of {}s does much the UserPropeties Count!

Here is the code and sample output:

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Private Sub ExractProperties(oMailItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim jsonSer As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sValue As String

    For i = 1 To oMailItem.UserProperties.Count
        Try
            sName = oMailItem.UserProperties.Item(i).Name
        Catch ex As Exception
            sName = ""
        End Try

        Try
            sValue = oMailItem.UserProperties.Item(i).Value.ToString()
        Catch ex As Exception
            sValue = ""
        End Try

        TextBoxProgress.Text = TextBoxProgress.Text & sName & ":" & sValue & vbCrLf
    Next

    TextBoxProgress.Text = TextBoxProgress.Text & jsonSer.Serialize(oMailItem.UserProperties) & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

Sample output (condensed)

```
1-RequestersName:sample name
1-RequestersOffice:sample office
1-RequestersOther:
1-RequestersPhone:12341234
1-RequestersRank:sample rank
1-ServiceRequested:
2-ServiceRequested:sample service
.
.
.
Approver:Sample Approver
ApproverPhone:12341234
ApproverUnit:Sample Unit
From:somebody
LastAction:Read
Sent:31/12/1999 6:25:13 PM
Subject:Sample Subject
To:Receiver

[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

Comment: I do nto see where your code outputs {}.

Comment: The code outputs to a TextBox!  I'm just checking things visually.  When the sub works I will change it to a string function that contains/returns the json string.

Comment: TextBoxProgress.Text = TextBoxProgress.Text & jsonSer.Serialize(oMailItem.UserProperties) & vbCrLf is the line of code that creates the {}s.  However I want it to create {somename:somevalue}.

Comment: me bad! I really want the code to just contain the line with jsonSer.Serialize. That's all it should need.  The rest of the code I added just to confirm there is something in the UserProperties collection.  So the entire for loop can dissapear!

Comment: Why do you think  jsonSer.Serialize will work wit ha COM collection?